# Angular 6 issue (Page needs a refresh to return data from server)

Tags: angular, routes

I have a small Angular 6 app with a simple router;

```js
const appRoutes:Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: LoginComponent
 },  
 {
   path: 'order-input/:ref/:name/:repref',
   //canActivate: [AuthguardGuard],
   component: OrderInputComponent
  },
  {
   path: 'order-input',
   canActivate: [AuthguardGuard],
   component: OrderInputComponent
 },  
 {
  path: 'trad-verify',
  canActivate: [AuthguardGuard],
  component: TradVerifyComponent
 },
 {
  path: '**',
  component: LoginComponent
 } 
]
```

I have an issue where if I open a browser and type or paste in a URL, that corresponds to one of the pages in the app, the page loads (order-input) but the requests to the server via the services seem to get stuck in a "pending" state and no data is returned.

If I hit refresh all is well and I get the data.

If I go the home page (localhost:4200) then open a new tab and type or paste the same URL things work OK.
I'm a bit confussed. can anyone help?

Here's the authgaurd

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from 
'@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from './local-storage.service';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor( private user: UserService,
           private router: Router,
           private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

let returnValue: boolean;

console.log("LoggedIn: ", this.localStorageService.getFromLocal('repref'))    

if (this.user.getUserLoggedIn()){
  return true;
}

if (this.localStorageService.getFromLocal('repref') != "" && this.localStorageService.getFromLocal('repref') != null) {
  return true;
}
  this.router.navigate(['']);  
  return false;

  }
}
```

Here's the ngOninit of order-input;

```
ngOnInit() {

  //pickup the ref, name from the url param
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {

...
  this.addressXref.getAddress(ref).subscribe(address => {
    this.xrefAddress = address["AddressXref"];

    for (let i in this.xrefAddress) {
      this.addressListItems.push({name: this.xrefAddress[i]["Name"], number: this.xrefAddress[i]["Number"]});
    }

    if (this.addressListItems.length  == 1) {
      this.selectedValue = this.addressListItems[0]["number"];
      this.addressNumber = this.selectedValue.toString();
    }

  })
```

User service;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { CONFIGURATION } from './configuration';

import { GlobalsService } from './globals.service';

import { LocalStorageService } from './local-storage.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  private _http : HttpClient;
....

  isValidUser(user, password) : Observable<any> {

    let loginService:string; 

    loginService = CONFIGURATION.serviceUrl + CONFIGURATION.loginService;
    loginService = loginService.replace("^1", user);
    loginService = loginService.replace("^2", password);
    loginService = loginService.replace("^3", Math.random().toString());

    return this._http.get(loginService, {withCredentials: true, responseType: 'json'})
    .pipe(
      map((val: any[]) => {

        if (val.hasOwnProperty("GoldUser")) {
          if (val["GoldUser"][0]["_Qy"] == "GoldSecurityUser") {
            this.setUserLoggedIn();
            this.setUserName(user);
            this.globalsService.personRef = val["GoldUser"][0]["PersonRef"];
            this.localStorageService.saveInLocal("repref", this.globalsService.personRef)
            return val;
          }
        }
        this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
        return false;
      }), catchError( error => { 
          console.log("error",error );
          alert("Invalid login details supplied");
          return throwError( 'Something went wrong with isValidUser!' )
        })
    );
  }
}

getUserLoggedIn() {
  return this.isUserLoggedIn;
}
```

Thanks,

Mark.

Comment: you should add the Guard and the service that used inside, so we can actually see whats the problem. You didn't provide any code that can help us.

Comment: Hopefully I've added the correct bits of code! :-)

Comment: I still need to see the user service, the function getUserLoggedIn()

Comment: Done. Let me know if there's any more you need to see? Thanks.

Comment: you didnt provide the whole service, but I think that your guard return a Boolean, but its not get the value from the service in time, so it stuck, but when you refresh, you have the localStorage service which holds the value so its works. try to return an Observable from the guard, and make the verification in the service to return Observable as well

Comment: Thanks, for advice. I will try this and let you know how it goes. Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the server redirect all requests to index.html as described here:
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Even when using ng serve (localhost:4200)?

Comment: ng serve does that automatically